# encodeURIComponent in ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

It seems encodeURIComponent is only allowed in AS 3, but because I'm using Flash Lite 3.1 I have to use AS 2. Any ideas for an alternative?

Comment: http://forums.adobe.com/message/113407#113407

Comment: but encodeURIComponent is not the same as escape.

Comment: I found this also http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary435.html

Comment: I have no idea how to use it.